# How can I get all graphics included into my Feature Layer using ArcGIS JS API 4?

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm load my Feature Layer from url and add it to map through property 'layers'. Then I need to highlight polygon and show info popup when click on it. I tried to use hitTest() method in click event from my Scene View, but I get 0 graphics in response. Maybe there is exist another decision to find graphic and highlight it?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a spatial query for all features that contain the point where the mouse clicked.

```
var query = layer.createQuery();
query.spatialRelationship = "contains";
query.geometry = mouseClickPoint;
query.returnGeometry = true;
layer.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
    // results contains the polygons that contain the point of mouse click
});
```